# Suitable model to be trained on Chinese COVID-19 data in order to forecast other countries data

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima

In an [article](https://www.who.int/docs/default-source/coronaviruse/who-china-joint-mission-on-covid-19-final-report.pdf) by WHO (World Health Organization) published on February 24, they present a very interesting plot (page 7) comparing symptom onset vs diagnosed cases for China. Since there is a lag time between the start of illness and diagnosis, the plot can give an idea of the true daily COVID-19 cases.

Knowing such information could, maybe, help to manage the emergency through prevention.

Symptom onset time series used in the article (Jan 1 - Feb 21)(cn = china):

`cn_onset = 50,50,50,50,70,50,80,120,100,190,190,210,290,300,490,560,720,790,950,1500,1690,2180,2670,2930,2890,3030,2970,2920,2620,2600,2450,3700,2300,2000,1880,1790,1390,1320,1070,920,940,700,650,620,420,380,300,300,350,170,90,90`

Diagnosis time series used in the article (Jan 1 - Feb 21):

`cn_cases = 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,80,280,320,620,920,900,1110,1480,1620,1880,2120,2550,2750,3120,3700,3550,3150,3320,2580,3610,2900,2410,2110,2060,1480,1090,980,1000,1090,630,630,820`

As we can see from the plot, few days after the lockdown the *true* daily cases started to decrease, where *true* stands for symptom onset.

[image]

My initial intent was to find an ARIMA model, train it on article data and test it on Italian data.

Using R functions on the Symptom onset series, we see that data is non-stationary(?) (p-value = 0.94), ACF has first 8 values and last 4 values significant, PACF has only first value significant, R suggests ARIMA(0,2,2) (moreover, AFC and PACF of the once differenced data have no significant values, does this mean something?)

Using R functions on the Diagnosis series, we see that data is stationary (p-value = 0.79), ACF has first 4 and last 6 values significant, PACF has only first value significant, R suggests ARIMA(1,0,0) with zero mean (also in this case, AFC and PACF of the once differenced data have no significant values).

Since I don't know yet how to use these models, I used a very rudimentaary and naive approach. I hope some more experienced users could run a more accurate analysis.

> OBJECTIVE: Use the above Chinese data to estimate the Italian symptom onset time series and to forecast the Italian diagnosis time series

Italian diagnosis time series provided by CSSE (Feb 20 - Mar 15)(it = italy):

`it_cases = 1,17,42,93,74,93,130,202,233,240,566,342,466,587,769,778,1247,1492,1797,1577,1713,2651,2547,3497,3590`

First, compute the rates of growth `rg` for the Onset series, it will be used to estimate the Italian onset series.

`rg(i+1) = cn_onset(i+1) / cn_onset(i)`

Second, compute the ratio of onset over diagnosis `ood` for each day from Jan 21, it will be used to predict/forecast the Italian diagnosis series.

`ood(i) = cn_onset(i) / cn_cases(i)`

Now, **to generate the Italian onset series** I thought about the following procedure

- the first value to be generated is the one corresponding to the Hubei lockdowns, which happened on January 23, and it is generated by multiplying the Italian diagnosis on March 10 (20th value inside `it_cases`), day of Italy lockdown, by the ratio of Chinese onset over diagnosis for January 23 (3rd value inside `ood`)

`it_onset(?) = ood(3) * it_cases(20) = 8.34 * 1577 = 13158 = reference value`

- the previous value, i.e. on March 9, is computed dividing the `reference value` by the rate of growth of the corresponding day in China, which was Jan 23 (lockdown)(22nd value in `rg`)

`it_onset(?-1) = it_onset(?) / rg(22)`

the value on March 8 is computed by `it_onset(?-2) = it_onset(?-1) / rg(21)`, and so until we reach February 17 (which corresponds to `rg(1)`).

- the next value, i.e. on March 16, is computed multiplying the `reference value` by the rate of growth of the corresponding day in China, which was Jan 24 (24th value in `rg`)

`it_onset(?+1) = it_onset(?) * rg(24)`

the value on March 17 is computed by `it_onset(?+2) = it_onset(?+1) / rg(25)`, and so until we reach April 8.

The total length of `it_onset` is 52, since `cn_onset` contains 52 values.

Now, to **forecast the Italian diagnosis series**, divide the Italian onset of each day by the corresponding Chinese ratio onset over diagnosis

`it_cases(25+i) = it_onset(28+i) / ood(8+i)`

[image]

In this plot, blue bars are the estimated symptom onset values in Italy, orange bars up to March 15 are the real daily cases in Italy, orange bars from March 16 onwards are the forecasted daily cases in Italy.

Basically this procedure is just a way to generate a symptom onset series with the same shape as the Chinese one, and to generate a forecast of the diagnosis series with the same shape as the Chinese diagnosis series from the lockdown onwards. So probably, this is the worst estimation possible, as one can also notice looking at the big jump between 3/15 and 3/16.

So, how to properly estimate symptom onset and forecast diagnosis?

P.S. if you are familiar with Python and Kaggle you can check my kernel [here](https://www.kaggle.com/giannit/estimation-of-italian-symptom-onset-and-forecast).

Comment: 1: How come you have data for >17 March and even into april? 2: The orange curve seems to be just a translated and smoothened version of the blue curve. The goal that you wish to achieve with this (training some model to model and predict this translation?) is not entirely clear to me. What is exactly the question here? Is it about relating/characterizing diagnosys with symptom onset or about predicting the curves?

Comment: It is very risky to train a model on one set of data and then use it on another set of data. The dataset might have a completely different basis and you can not learn the discrepancies from the data if you only have two single examples (China and Italy), although you might think it is robust because you have a lot of cases/data (albeit it is still only two independent cases).

Comment: Is your question about how to analyze these data with an ARIMA model? How did you analyze this? I can imagine that there could be some correlation between the diagnosis and onset but is this what you are analyzing with an ARIMA model, or does that model apply more to the *single* time series, rather than their relation? In addition, how was the syptom onset derivred7measured? I imagine that the onset is not a direct measure and just derived backwards based on reports about the *relative* onset of symptoms. If that is the case, then you might just as well, etter analyze those reports directly.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus The objective is highlighted in the middle of the question, and below it, it is described how I computed the forecast in detail (I did not use ARIMA). I guess symptom onset data was obtained by asking positive patients when they first showed symptoms. Since incubation time is not the same for everybody, the onset series is not exactly a shifted version of the diagnosis series, but it can still give information about the future diagnosis. The main difference between China and Italy data is that China immediately applied the lockdown, while Italy waited for two weeks.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus I think that the analysis of the reported cases only is less precise than the analysis which considers both onset and reported cases, since the onset series can give you an idea of what is going to happen, and it doesn't sound like a bad idea thinking that briefly after the lockdown the onset series will decrease. I don't know which are the best models to use in cases like these. I mentioned ARIMA models just because I don't know about other models used to forecast data. If you had to forecast reported cases for another country using Chinese data, what would you do?

Comment: I get your ARIMA model now.  I agree with your smart trick to use some sort of Kernel method that predicts growth as a sum of previous values. But a big problem is that we can not reliably estimate the parameters (and also they should not be considered constants as in a regular ARIMA model.   *"If you had to forecast reported cases for another country using Chinese data, what would you do?"* gather more data. We should not copy the curve from China and apply it to Italy. (although we can use the knowledge from thje China case that shows that the response to actions will be delayed)